# Only first rule of parser being accepted ( using ply with python)

Tags: parsing, lex, ply

Im trying to build a Lexer and Parser for a project , i already did the Lexer and now i am trying to do the parser

Lexer:

```
reserved = {
    'if' : 'IF',
    'else' : 'ELSE',
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    'do'    : 'DO',
    'for'   : 'FOR',
    'main'  : 'MAIN',
    'int'   : 'INT_ID',
    'float' : 'FLOAT_ID',
    'char'  : 'CHAR_ID'
 }
tokens = ['CHAR', 'FLOAT','INTEGER', 'PLUS', 'MINUS', 'MUL', 'DIV','OPEN_PAR', 'CLOSE_PAR','OPEN_BRACKETS','CLOSE_BRACKETS','ASSIGNMENT', 'EQUALS', 'NOT_EQUALS', 'EQUAL_OR_GREATER_THAN', 
        'EQUAL_OR_LESS_THAN', 'LESS_THAN', 'GREATER_THAN', 'COMMA', 'SEMI_COLON','IDENTIFIER','NEWLINE','COMMENT_EOL',"COMMENT_DELIMITED"] + list(reserved.values())



t_PLUS    = r'\+'
t_MINUS   = r'-'
t_MUL   = r'\*'
t_DIV  = r'/'
t_OPEN_PAR  = r'\('
t_CLOSE_PAR  = r'\)'
t_OPEN_BRACKETS  = r'\{'
t_CLOSE_BRACKETS  = r'\}'
t_ASSIGNMENT  = r'\='
t_EQUALS  = r'\=\='
t_NOT_EQUALS  = r'\!\='
t_EQUAL_OR_GREATER_THAN  = r'\>\='
t_EQUAL_OR_LESS_THAN  = r'\<\='
t_LESS_THAN = r'\<'
t_GREATER_THAN = r'\>'
t_COMMA = r'\,'
t_SEMI_COLON = r'\;'

def t_COMMENT_EOL(t):
    r'\/{2}.*\n'
    return t

def t_COMMENT_DELIMITED(t):
    r'\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/'
    return t

def t_CHAR(t):
    r'\'[a-zA-Z]\'' 
    return t

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'[-]?[0-9]*\.{1}[0-9]+'
    t.value = float(t.value)    
    return t

def t_INTEGER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)    
    return t


def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    #  r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\_{1}[0-9]*$)*'
     r'[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+'
     t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'IDENTIFIER')    # Check for reserved words
     return t


def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


t_ignore  = ' \t'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()
```

Parser (Some rules are yet not made):

```
 # Get the token map from the lexer.  This is required.
from lexer import tokens


#valorvariaveis
def p_float(p):
    'float : FLOAT'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_integer(p):
    'int : INTEGER'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_char(p):
    'char : CHAR'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_id(p):
    'id : IDENTIFIER'
    p[0] = p[1]
#fim valorvariaveis


#decl_var
def p_decl_var(p):
    'decl_var : type id SEMI_COLON'
    p[0] = p[1]


#tipovariaveis
def p_INT_ID(p):
    'type : INT_ID'
    p[0] = p[1]
def p_FLOAT_ID(p):
    'type : FLOAT_ID'
    p[0] = p[1]
def p_CHAR_ID(p):
    'type : CHAR_ID'
    p[0] = p[1]


#program
def p_program(p):
    'program : INT_ID MAIN OPEN_PAR CLOSE_PAR'
#block
def p_block(p):
    'block : OPEN_BRACKETS decl_var command CLOSE_BRACKETS'
    p[0] = p[1]


#command
def p_command_basic_command(p):
    'command : basic_command'
    p[0] = p[1] 

def p_command_iteration(p):
    'command : iteration'
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_command(p):
    'command : IF OPEN_PAR expr_relacional CLOSE_PAR command OPEN_BRACKETS ELSE command CLOSE_BRACKETS'
    p[0] = p[1] 




#basic_command
def p_basic_command_assignment(p):
    'basic_command : assignment'
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_basic_command_block(p):
    'basic_command : block'
    p[0] = p[1] 



#iteration
def p_iteration_WHILE(p):
    'iteration : WHILE OPEN_PAR expr_relacional CLOSE_PAR command'
    #FALTA FAZER AQUIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_iteration_DO(p):
    'iteration : DO command WHILE OPEN_PAR expr_relacional CLOSE_PAR SEMI_COLON'
    #FALTA FAZER AQUIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
    p[0] = p[1] 



#atribuicao
def p_assignment(p):
    'assignment : id ASSIGNMENT expression_arit SEMI_COLON'
    p[0] = p[1] 



#oprelacional
def p_op_relacional_GREATER_THAN(p):
    'op_relacional : GREATER_THAN'
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_op_relacional_LESS_THAN(p):
    'op_relacional : LESS_THAN'
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_op_relacional_EQUAL_OR_LESS_THAN(p):
    'op_relacional : EQUAL_OR_LESS_THAN'
    p[0] = p[1] 
def p_op_relacional_EQUAL_OR_GREATER_THAN(p):
    'op_relacional : EQUAL_OR_GREATER_THAN'
    p[0] = p[1] 



#expr_relacional
def p_expr_relacional(p):
    'expr_relacional : expression_arit op_relacional expression_arit'
    print("oioioi")
    if p[2] == '>=':
        if p[1] >= p[3]:
            p[0]=True
        else:
            p[0]=False
    elif p[2] == '<=':
        if p[1] <= p[3]:
            p[0]=True
        else:
            p[0]=False
    elif p[2] == '<':
        if p[1] < p[3]:
            p[0]=True
        else:
            p[0]=False
    elif p[2] == '>':
        if p[1] > p[3]:
            p[0]=True
        else:
            p[0]=False



#expression_arit
def p_expression_arit_plus(p):
    'expression_arit : expression_arit PLUS term'
    p[0] = p[1] + p[3]

def p_expression_arit_minus(p):
    'expression_arit : expression_arit MINUS term'
    p[0] = p[1]- p[3]

def p_expression_arit(p):
    'expression_arit : term'
    p[0] = p[1]
#fim expression_arit




#term
def p_term_mul(p):
    'term : term MUL factor'
    p[0] = p[1] * p[3]

def p_term_div(p):
    'term : term DIV factor'
    p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_term_factor(p):
    'term : factor'
    p[0] = p[1]
#fim term



#fator
def p_factor_expr(p):
    'factor : OPEN_PAR expression_arit CLOSE_PAR'
    p[0] = p[2]


def p_factor_integer(p):
    'factor : int'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_factor_float(p):
    'factor : float'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_factor_id(p):
    'factor : id'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_factor_char(p):
    'factor : char'
    p[0] = p[1]


# Error rule for syntax errors
def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error in input!")

# Build the parser
parser = yacc.yacc()

while True:
    try:
        s = input('calc > ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not s: continue
    result = parser.parse(s)
    print(result)
```

What is happening is that the only rule being accepted is the first one ( the float one ) all the other ones are unreachable and i dont know why

```
calc > 1.0
1.0
calc > 1
Syntax error in input!
None
calc >
```

You see a inputted "1.0" and the Parser gives no message errors , but when i try to input a integer like "1" it gives a error .

But there is a Rule for INTEGER numbers

Answer (score 0):

Ply always starts parsing with the first rule in your file, unless you specify a different one. See the [formidable manual](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn28).

Comment: The order ir put the rules matters ?? How do i make it all connected ?

Comment: Your rules are "connected" because each one names its components, the same way that your program's functions are "connected" because they call each other by name. But your program also has to communicate where it is supposed to start. In C, that's done by insisting that the starting point is called "main". Ply chooses not to insist on a special name; it uses the first rule it sees as its starting point unless you tell it where to start, as explained in the link I provided.

Comment: @GuilhermeSiqueira: ^^